# Как реагировать на сообщение из другого чата?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Спасибо за внимание. Пытаюсь написать магазин-бот в Telegram(автоматическая продажа электронного товара), попутно изучая Python. Так как простых способов привязать оплату через Qiwi не удалось, решил просто перенаправлять реквизиты из чата с покупателем менеджеру и обрабатывать их в ручном режиме.
**Нужно дождаться, пока в чате Б (с менеджером) напишут сообщение X, и по его получению отправить ответ в чат А (с покупателем).** На данный момент додумался лишь до сообщения менеджеру:

```
bot.send_message(manager_id, 'Поступил заказ на оплату,продукт с ID {}, 
кошелек {}, сумма {}. ID покупателя: @{}. Подтвердить?'.format(message.text, 
number[message.text],price[message.text],message.from_user.username))
```

Как правильно организовать ответ на это сообщение?

Comment: У telegram есть способ работать с qiwi. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#payments

Comment: @Redr01d
_Special Note: Due to Apple's limitations, bot developers are currently not allowed to accept payments for digital goods and virtual services from iOS users._